# What makes a shell "POSIX compliant"?

Tags: shell, command-line

I am getting quite tired of how Shells on Windows work - and, there aren't that many options. So I have considered just writing my own shell. However, whilst reading some documentation about the scripts generated by autotools, I noticed that sometimes, "SH compliant" or "POSIX-like compliant shell" is used.

As far as I know, Bash scripts are incompatible with Fish for instance, since `&&` is replaced by a literal `and` - and that is only one difference I could spot from a glance.

So what would a shell need to be "SH compliant" or "POSIX-like compliant shell"? Aside from reading commands to be executed and storing a few variables, there is not a whole lot a shell really does so I would assume it's only syntacticaly. Or, am I mistaken?

Comment: `and that is only one difference` The "_only_"... ?

Comment: @KamilCuk That is *only one* difference, (and there are many more that follows).

Comment: @IngwiePhoenix : It means that it follows [this](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/FIPS/fipspub189.pdf)  standard, An easier reading of the matter, which seems to cover it quite well, can be found [here](https://shellhaters.org/).

Comment: So I would say you should use fish as your modern shell. You can't run bash scripts directly in it(this work in almost all posix like shells), but this easily circumvented by `script.sh| sh`; It only being almost posix is far outweighed by it's easy of use, and how much it improves your productivity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So what would a shell need to be "SH compliant" or "POSIX-like compliant shell"?

It would need to follow the behavior as specified by the [POSIX standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX). POSIX is an open standard - you can read it online at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ . See section [Shell & Utilities 2. Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18) for documentation related to shell behavior.

There are no (at least I am not aware) certification companies that would certificate a specific shell program as "POSIX compliant". The whole operation systems are getting [POSIX-certified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX-certified) and then these operating systems come with a POSIX-compatible shell. In the case of projects that do not have enough funds to get an external company for certification, it's usually in the will of the author to say if he aims for his creation to be POSIX compatible or not, and if he does, then the users expect the shell to behave as specified by POSIX.

> Bash scripts are incompatible with Fish for instance

From [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

> It is intended to be a conformant implementation of the IEEE POSIX Shell and Tools portion of the IEEE POSIX specification (IEEE Standard 1003.1).

From [fish home page](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/):

> Unlike other shells, fish does not follow the POSIX standard, but still uses roughly the same model.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know software could in fact be certified for conformance to POSIX in the first place - that's pretty cool actually. Those will be good reads for sure!