# GitHub Action to periodically update toolchain versions?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a GitHub project that [pins Rust toolchain versions](https://github.com/google/zerocopy/blob/03551ce77237e86bfd90a326b22a918154385230/Cargo.toml#L26) for use in CI. So far, I've been periodically updating these versions manually.

It's a rote task that, from a scripting perspective, is trivial to automate. As in, it's literally be this simple:

```bash
# After updating Cargo.toml
VERSION=$(cargo metadata --format-version 1 |\
    jq -r ".packages[] | select(.name == \"zerocopy\").metadata.ci.pinned-stable)

TRYBUILD=overwrite cargo +$VERSION test --all
git commit -am '[CI] Update pinned stable toolchain version'
```

However, is there a way that I can configure a GitHub action to periodically run this script and submit a PR automatically? I'd still manually review the PRs, of course.

Comment: You might get some ideas on how to configure Dependabot for that https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuring-dependabot-version-updates

Comment: Looks like Dependabot doesn't support this unfortunately. You're required to specify a [package-ecosystem](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#package-ecosystem), and what I'm describing doesn't use a package manager - it's just our own bespoke thing. It happens to piggy-back on the `Cargo.toml` file, but it doesn't actually use Cargo in the sense that Dependabot does.

Comment: One possible solution could be to configure a cron job using [`on.schedule`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onschedule) along with [GitHub CLI](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows) to create the PR for your review i.e. [`gh pr create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. Here's the GitHub Actions config file:

```yaml
name: Roll pinned toolchain versions
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '29 15 * * *'

# TODO: Once we confirm this works, try changing this to `read-all` to see if
# the job still works.
permissions: write-all

jobs:
  roll:
    name: Roll pinned toolchain versions
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "Checkout code"
        uses: actions/checkout@3df4ab11eba7bda6032a0b82a6bb43b11571feac # v4.0.0
        with:
          ref: main
      - name: "Calculate target version"
        # Use yesterday's date (`-d '-1 day'`) so we're sure the nightly for that
        # date has actually been published yet. This allows us to not worry
        # about what time of day this job runs.
        run: echo "ZC_TARGET_NIGHTLY=nightly-$(date -d '-1 day' +%Y-%m-%d)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Install Rust with ${{ env.ZC_TARGET_NIGHTLY }} toolchain
        uses: dtolnay/rust-toolchain@00b49be78f40fba4e87296b2ead62868750bdd83 # stable
        with:
            toolchain: ${{ env.ZC_TARGET_NIGHTLY }}
      - name: "Update files"
        run: |
          set -eox pipefail
          # Confirm that `Cargo.toml` lists the pinned nightly version in the
          # expected format. This is a prerequisite for the subsequent `sed`
          # command. If this fails, the preceding `set -eo pipefail` will cause
          # the script to exit with an error.
          REGEX='^pinned-nightly = "[a-z0-9-]*"$'
          grep "$REGEX" Cargo.toml >/dev/null
          sed -i -e "s/$REGEX/pinned-nightly = \"$ZC_TARGET_NIGHTLY\"/" Cargo.toml
          # Confirm that the update didn't bork `Cargo.toml`.
          grep "$REGEX" Cargo.toml >/dev/null
          # Update `.stderr` files as needed for the new nightly version.
          TRYBUILD=overwrite ./cargo.sh +nightly test --all-features --package zerocopy
          TRYBUILD=overwrite ./cargo.sh +nightly test --all-features --package zerocopy-derive
      
      - name: "Submit PR"
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@153407881ec5c347639a548ade7d8ad1d6740e38 # v5.0.2
        with:
          commit-message: "[ci] Roll pinned nightly toolchain"
          branch: roll-pinned-toolchain-to-${{ env.ZC_TARGET_NIGHTLY }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77152344/6309), you might consider using consistent naming conventions. Mixed cases in environment variable names, job names, and step names can make it harder to read and maintain the code.
You could also use tagged versions for your plugins, instead of pinning a specific commit hash (except for [`dtolnay/rust-toolchain`](https://github.com/dtolnay/rust-toolchain), which has no tag, only branches).

Regarding the script, it should gracefully handle errors and report them for easier debugging. While `set -eox pipefail` is good for debug information, explicit error messages would make it easier to troubleshoot issues.

For instance:

```yaml
name: Update Pinned Nightly Toolchain
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '29 15 * * *'

permissions: write-all

jobs:
  update_toolchain:
    name: Update Pinned Nightly Toolchain
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: main
          
      - name: Calculate Target Version
        run: echo "ZC_TARGET_NIGHTLY=nightly-$(date -d '-1 day' +%Y-%m-%d)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        
      - name: Install Rust with ${{ env.ZC_TARGET_NIGHTLY }} toolchain
        uses: dtolnay/rust-toolchain@00b49be78f40fba4e87296b2ead62868750bdd83 # stable
        with:
            toolchain: ${{ env.ZC_TARGET_NIGHTLY }}
          
      - name: Update Files
        run: |
          set -eox pipefail
          REGEX='^pinned-nightly = "[a-z0-9-]*"$'
          if ! grep -q "$REGEX" Cargo.toml; then
            echo "Format for pinned-nightly not found in Cargo.toml"
            exit 1
          fi
          sed -i -e "s/$REGEX/pinned-nightly = \"$ZC_TARGET_NIGHTLY\"/" Cargo.toml
          grep "$REGEX" Cargo.toml >/dev/null || { echo "Update to Cargo.toml failed"; exit 1; }
          TRYBUILD=overwrite cargo +nightly test --all-features --package zerocopy
          TRYBUILD=overwrite cargo +nightly test --all-features --package zerocopy-derive

      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v5
        with:
          commit-message: '[CI] Roll pinned nightly toolchain'
          title: 'Update Pinned Nightly Toolchain to ${{ env.TARGET_NIGHTLY }}'
          branch: roll-pinned-toolchain-to-${{ env.TARGET_NIGHTLY }}
```

---

> TIL about that use of curly braces as a subexpression that doesn't create a sub-shell like `(...)`.

The use of curly braces `{}` in shell scripting is an important feature, particularly in [POSIX-compliant](https://superuser.com/a/322602/141) [shells like `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67684382/6309). These braces allow you to group commands together as a single unit, without spawning a new sub-shell. That is, unlike parentheses `()`, which do create a sub-shell for the enclosed commands.

- Because curly braces do not spawn a new sub-shell, any variables you set or modify within the braces are available outside them.
- Since a new sub-shell is not created, the operation is slightly faster and uses fewer system resources.
- You can apply I/O redirection to the entire group of commands inside the braces.
- It allows you to logically group a set of commands to execute together.

In the provided YAML snippet for the GitHub Action, the use of curly braces `{}` around `echo "Update to Cargo.toml failed"; exit 1;` serves as a way to group these commands together. The key importance here lies in the context of the `||` operator that precedes it.

The `||` operator in shell scripting runs the command following it only if the command preceding it fails (returns a non-zero exit code). In this case, the command that precedes `||` is `grep "$REGEX" Cargo.toml >/dev/null`. If this `grep` command fails, meaning it does not find the specified regex in `Cargo.toml`, then the script will execute the commands within the curly braces.

If you did *not* use the curly braces:

```bash
grep "$REGEX" Cargo.toml >/dev/null || echo "Update to Cargo.toml failed"; exit 1;
```

In this case, `exit 1` would get executed regardless of whether `grep` succeeds or fails, which is not the intended behavior. The script would always exit with a status code of 1, causing the GitHub Action to fail every time it runs.

By using curly braces:

```bash
grep "$REGEX" Cargo.toml >/dev/null || { echo "Update to Cargo.toml failed"; exit 1; }
```

Both `echo "Update to Cargo.toml failed"` and `exit 1` are grouped together, ensuring that if `grep` fails, both the `echo` and `exit` commands will be executed in that specific order. That way, an error message is printed, and the script exits with a failure status, halting the GitHub Action as intended.

Comment: Woah, TIL about that use of curly braces as a subexpression that doesn't create a sub-shell like `(...)`. I've been wanting that for a while. On that basis alone, I'll give you the bounty once I'm able to in 15 hours.

Comment: Also, the pinned hashes for GitHub Actions are because we use Dependabot to keep deps updated; that's the format output by Dependabot.

Comment: @joshlf I have edited the answer to document the `{...}` curly braces feature.